# mount drives at boot failed

Tags: openvpn, systemd, sshfs

For mounting sshfs I have a shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash 
sshfs -o allow_other user@ip-address:/remote/path /local path
```

If I run the script after I boot up the server, it will mount, but it won't mount drives if I add the script to run at boot with `/etc/rc.local` or crontab using @reboot command.
I also tried to add sshfs lines to `/etc/fstab`, but that fails too.

I tried to add this to `/etc/fstab`

```
sshfs#user@remote:/path /local/path
```

then server won't boot up

Comment: At `/etc/rc.local` execution time, the environment is not the same as it is later.  Run `env | /usr/bin/sort >/tmp/env.$(/bin/date +%y%b%d-%H%M%S)` in both places, and compare the 2 files.

Comment: Your line in `/etc/fstab` is missing mandatory parameters. Try this: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSHFS#On_boot